# Programmatically add multiple categories to Outlook 2010

Tags: c#, outlook-2010

I am trying to create multiple categories in Outlook 2010 using C#. I am able to successfully generate an executable that will create one category but when I add code to create a second category it will still only add the first one and not the second. If The first category exists it will then add the second one but it will not create both from scratch at the same time.

Below is my code. Any help is greatly appreciated.

```
using System;
using System.Linq;
using Outlook = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook;
using Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook;


namespace OutlookCategory
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            AddACategory();
        }

        private static void AddACategory()
        {
            var app = new Application();
            Outlook.Categories categories = app.Session.Categories;
            if (!CategoryExists("TEST 1", app))
            {
                categories.Add("TEST 1", Outlook.OlCategoryColor.olCategoryColorDarkBlue);
            }
            if (!CategoryExists("TEST 2", app))
            {
                categories.Add("TEST 2", Outlook.OlCategoryColor.olCategoryColorDarkBlue);
            }

        }

        private static bool CategoryExists(string categoryName, Application app)
        {
            try
            {
                Outlook.Category category =
                    app.Session.Categories[categoryName];
                if (category != null)
                {
                    return true;
                }
                else
                {
                    return false;
                }
            }
            catch { return false; }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Just wanted to bump this - as I've just experienced the same problem...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up accomplishing this by creating a pipe delimited text file with my category names and their associated category color.

I then looped through the text file creating all of the categories in Outlook.

```
using System;
using System.IO;
using Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook;
using Outlook = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook;


namespace OutlookCategory
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            AddACategory();
        }
        private static void AddACategory()
        {
            string[] lines = File.ReadAllLines(@"C:\CategoryList.txt");
            var app = new Application(); 
            foreach (string line in lines)
            {
                string[] LineArray = line.Split('|');                               
                var color = LineArray[1];

                Outlook.Categories categories = app.Session.Categories;
                //Add categories
                if (CategoryExists(LineArray[0], app) == false)
                {
                    categories.Add(LineArray[0], color);
                }
            }
        }
        private static bool CategoryExists(string categoryName, Application app)
        {
            try
            {
                Outlook.Category category =
                    app.Session.Categories[categoryName];
                if (category != null)
                {
                    return true;
                }
                else
                {
                    return false;
                }
            }
            catch { return false; }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The answer already provided did not do the trick for me. I would still get spotty results while adding and removing categories. i was able to get around this by trying the add/remove, then re-getting the categories and looping until the item was added/removed as needed.

Here is code snipped from LinqPad where I would remove all of the categories, add back in my own, then list some categories and their values. This has worked with no problems since i switched to the while/loop check. I tried a few different sleep times and it didn't seem to make much of a difference. I am guessing outlook must need to do something before the new category actually 'goes in' to the datastore. Regardless, I didn't want to spend a ton of time on this, and this worked for me. I am using outlook 2010 on windows 7. not sure if newer versions of office have this same issue.

```
void Main()
{

    //using Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook
    Application oApp = new Application();
    NameSpace oSes = oApp.Session;
    Categories oCats = oSes.DefaultStore.Categories;

    //remove existing categories
    var catids = (from a in oCats.Cast<Category>() select a.CategoryID).ToArray();
    for (int i = 0; i < catids.Count(); i++)
    {
        var cid = catids[i];
        cid.Dump();
        while(oCats[cid] != null)
        {
            oCats.Remove(cid);
            oCats = oSes.DefaultStore.Categories;
            Thread.Sleep(100);
        }
    }

    //dictionary to hold my categories
    Dictionary<string,OlCategoryColor> dCats = new Dictionary<string,OlCategoryColor>();
    dCats.Add("Category One",OlCategoryColor.olCategoryColorRed);
    dCats.Add("Category Two",OlCategoryColor.olCategoryColorOrange);
    dCats.Add("Category Three",OlCategoryColor.olCategoryColorPeach);
    dCats.Add("Category Four",OlCategoryColor.olCategoryColorYellow);

    foreach (var dCat in dCats)
    {
        var cid = dCat.Key;
        cid.Dump();
        while(oCats[cid] == null)
        {
            oCats.Add(cid,dCat.Value);
            oCats = oSes.DefaultStore.Categories;
            Thread.Sleep(100);
        }
    }

    //show categories
    var cats = from c in oCats.Cast<Category>() select new {
        c.CategoryBorderColor,
        c.CategoryGradientBottomColor,
        c.CategoryGradientTopColor,
        c.CategoryID,
        c.Class,
        c.Color,
        c.Name,
        c.ShortcutKey
    };
    cats.Dump();

}
```